# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'isAdmin' of null

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if(user) {
    this.isLoggedIn = true; //Set user loggedIn is true;
    this.isAdmin = false;
    firebase.database().ref('/userProfile/' + user.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      let userInfo = snapshot.val();
      if(userInfo.isAdmin == true) {
        //ERROR AT THIS LINE: 
        //Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'isAdmin' of null
        this.isAdmin = true;
        console.log(userInfo);
      }
    });
  } else {
    this.isLoggedIn = false; //Set user loggedIn is false;
  }
});
```

I'm getting error at line no.8

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'isAdmin' of null

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either you can use arrow function

```
firebase.database().ref('/userProfile/' + user.uid).once('value')
.then((snapshot) => {
```

or use

```
var self = this;

firebase.database().ref('/userProfile/' + user.uid).once('value')
.then(function(snapshot) {
   self.isAdmin = true;
```

otherwise `this` doesn't point to the current function when it's called.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: This answer is correct. The `this` scope changes inside the Firebase Database callback, so you need to properly keep the reference.

Comment: @Gunter do you have a page on angular 2 I can read about this' scope?

Comment: See the link I added to the answer. It's an old JS problem.