# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'empolyee' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular4-router

I want to get employee object by id from **employee.serves.ts** File to **employee-info.component.ts** file in order to view data of this object in HTML.

The main question is how can I get object by id from firestore ? (only one object  not all id objects in the collection)

**doc.data()** in **employee.serves.ts** file gave me the object that I want, but how can I send this data to **employee-info.component.ts** in order to view it in the HTML.

**employee.serves.ts File**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Employee } from '../models/Employee';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {
    employeesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Employee>;

    empolyee: Observable<Employee>;

    constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
        this.employeesCollection = this.afs.collection('employees');
    }

    getEmployee(id){
        this.employeesCollection.doc(id).ref.get().then(function(doc) {
            this.empolyee = doc.data();
        });
        return this.empolyee;
    }
}
```

**employee-info.component.ts File**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from '../../services/employee.service';
import { Employee } from '../../models/Employee';
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-employee-info',
    templateUrl: './employee-info.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./employee-info.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeInfoComponent implements OnInit {
    id: string;
    employee : Employee;

    hasSalary: boolean = false;
    updateSalary: boolean = false;

    constructor(private employeeServaice: EmployeeService, 
                private router: Router,
                private activateRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private fmService: FlashMessagesModule ) { 

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = this.activateRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.employeeServaice.getEmployee(this.id).subscribe(employee => {
            this.employee = employee;
            console.log(this.employee);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: *"The main question is how can I get Object by id from firestore"* Um...how does the title of your question relate to that (and to your question)?

Comment: The problem mentioned in the title is that `this` is undefined inside of `getEmployee`'s callback function. The solution is to define the callback as an arrow function `this.employeesCollection.doc(id).ref.get().then((doc) => { ... }`. That problem is reported so often on StackOverflow that I won't write an answer. :-)

Comment: Here are a few references for the same problem: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38807661/1009922), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48010059/1009922), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030729/1009922), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838760/1009922).

Answer (score 0):

```
 getEmployee(id){
        this.employeesCollection.doc(id).ref.get().then(function(doc) {
            this.empolyee = doc.data();
        });
        return this.empolyee;
 }

 // Use Arrow function inside callback 

 getEmployee(id){
        this.employeesCollection.doc(id).ref.get().then((doc) => {
            this.empolyee = doc.data();
        });
        return this.empolyee;
 }
```